# how to know what model we kneed to use get specipic data using orm

Tags: magento-1.9

I am learning magento orm.I know get data using orm.but my problam is how i exacly know which model responcible for give specipic data.
as example I know if I want get product name I use $`collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`  but is there any documentation like this model responsible for give that data.
as example if i want to get cart data what model I used etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take a look at `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`.With this call you will get instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class, defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php`.

First part of `catalog/product`, `catalog`, comes from modules configuration, and is usually the same as name of module folder. In `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml` you can see this declaration:

```
         <models>
            <catalog>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model</class>
            </catalog>
            .........
         <models>
```

The second part of `catalog/product`, `product`, is our class defined under Model folder, `Product.php`

Magento is able to do that by using factory design pattern(in the same way you can get the instance of helpers and blocks). If you want to understand better how it works, take a look in `app/Mage.php` at `getModel()` function.

Now, the Magento entities are self explanatory. For example, if you want to use `cart` model just call it like that `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')`. Here `checkout` is the module, and `cart` is the php class under Model folder. Just take a look in that model class and you will find the methods available.

Good luck !